# Error saving geodaframe to shp: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_file'

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, shapely, geodataframe

I have been struggling with a problem related to [Getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file' from GeoPandas even though file converted into GeoDataframe instead of Dataframe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291566/geopandas-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-to-file-even-th) but it is not exactly the same.

I created a point geopandas dataframe and saved it to a shapefile without a problem

```
pnt_data = {'geometry': [<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x7fa9820ffd10>, <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x7fa95739ea90>,...

gp_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pnt_data, crs=crs)
gp_df.to_file(path_to_file, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Now I want to save a line shapefile with the same points. Based on what I've read, I tried the following:

```
lineCoords = [(500191.6, 7656332.248), (500222.84883889696,
               7656358.309988857),...]
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(lineCoords, crs=crs)
```

which got me the following dataframe

```
                                 geometry
0                  (500191.6, 7656332.248)
1  (500222.84883889696, 7656358.309988857)
2   (500238.1988799781, 7656371.130918575)
3  (500254.99698246736, 7656381.985583601)
4    (500273.2863161564, 7656390.07880751)
5  (500292.37426232523, 7656396.049595658)
6  (500312.1612412515, 7656398.9608608475)
7  (500331.89439794194, 7656402.217013037)
8  (500351.87729180406, 7656403.044027512)
9  (500371.78081168584, 7656401.081912234)
```

The only attribute that interests me are the coordinates and they are there. However, when I tried to save this to a shapefile using the same procedure I used for points

```
gp_df.to_file(path_to_file, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

and got the error message

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_z'
```

Based on a similar problem I found that the solution could have been

```
gp_df['geometry'].to_file(filename, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

At this point I got the error in the title:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_file'
```

I also tried to convert the list of tuples with the coordinates to a linestring and do the same procedure

```
finalData = LineString (lineCoords)
gp_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(finalData, crs=crs)
```

In this case I got

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Some recommended to use the raw list instead of the linestring, which was why I started the path above.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I was creating the dataframe with a wrong shape. The way it worked for me was to make sure the vertices were contained within a single object

```
finalLine_data = {'id': [1], 'geometry':[LineString(lineCoords)]}
gp_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(finalLine_data, crs=crs)
gp_df['geometry'].to_file(path_to_file, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

The finalLine_data looks like this

```
{'id': [1], 'geometry': [<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f42af79c290>]}
   id                                           geometry
0   1  LINESTRING (500191.600 7656332.248, 500223.849...
```