# AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_flie'

Tags: python, geopandas

I meet a different error——Getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file' from GeoPandas even though file converted into GeoDataframe instead of Dataframe ([Getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file' from GeoPandas even though file converted into GeoDataframe instead of Dataframe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291566/getting-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-to-file-from-geopa))

My code is such as:

```
shp5.to_flie('/mnt/d/tmp/arcgispro_test/graduate_paper/data/merge_thick3.shp')
```

and got a error message：

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
`enter code here`/tmp/ipykernel_535/2735828028.py in <module>
----> 1 shp5.to_flie('/mnt/d/tmp/arcgispro_test/graduate_paper/data/merge_thick3.shp')

~/anaconda3/envs/oggm_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5476         ):
   5477             return self[name]
-> 5478         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5479 
   5480     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_flie'
```

I'm sure shp5 is a GeoDataFrame

```
print(type(shp5))
```

it returned:

```
    <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
```

shp5's attributes table  are as follow:     ​

```
OBJECTID    GlaThiDa_I  POLITICAL_  GLACIER_NA  SURVEY_DAT  POINT_ID    POINT_LAT   POINT_LON   ELEVATION   THICKNESS   ... Aspect  Lmax    Status  Connect Form    TermType    Surging Linkages    Name    geometry
0   1   2086.0  CN  SIGONGHE GLACIER NO.4   20099999.0  1   43.841081   88.311338   3640.0  26.0    ... 328 2882    0   0   0   0   9   9   CN5Y725D0004    POINT (88.31134 43.84108)
1   2   2086.0  CN  SIGONGHE GLACIER NO.4   20099999.0  2   43.841071   88.311373   3640.0  26.0    ... 328 2882    0   0   0   0   9   9   CN5Y725D0004    POINT (88.31137 43.84107)
2   3   2086.0  CN  SIGONGHE GLACIER NO.4   20099999.0  3   43.841057   88.311422   3644.0  27.0    ... 328 2882    0   0   0   0   9   9   CN5Y725D0004    POINT (88.31142 43.84106)
3   4   2086.0  CN  SIGONGHE GLACIER NO.4   20099999.0  4   43.841048   88.311453   3644.0  27.0    ... 328 2882    0   0   0   0   9   9   CN5Y725D0004    POINT (88.31145 43.84105)
4   5   2086.0  CN  SIGONGHE GLACIER NO.4   20099999.0  5   43.841023   88.311536   3648.0  27.0    ... 328 2882    0   0   0   0   9   9   CN5Y725D0004    POINT (88.31154 43.84102)
```

I am a newcomer in Python and search for the problem in GitHub, but can't find the way to solve it.

Comment: You have a misspelling- `shp5.to_flie()` should be `shp5.to_file()`.

Comment: I‘m so sorry...and thanks